# Problem adding a pivot table connected to a PowerBI dataset in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi

I open a new empty excel workbook, and then try to insert a Pivot Table connected to a power BI dataset.

[image]

Normally the datasets that I have access to should be displayed in the pane on the right, but now this pane is completely empty.

[image]

There are no error messages.

If I instead go to app.powerbi.com, and log in with the same user, I can access all my datasets as expected.

This functionality has worked before. It seems that there has been a recent change somewhere that is causing this problem. It might be a windows update, an automatic update to Excel, some change on the Power BI server side, or perhaps some unknown change in our corporate firewall.

There is a valid workaround by navigating to the dataset in app.powerbi.com and selecting "Analyze in Excel", but I really want to have this work from inside Excel.

I have tried restarting my computer with no change.
Some of my colleagues have the same problem, and some do not have this problem.

The version of Excel I am using is Version 2304 Build 16327

Any ideas?